# Problema para pegar dados Array Multidimenssional

Tags: php

estou com um problema para pegar os dados de um arquivo json! Bom inicialmente eu recebo o Json via CURL POST e efetuo o decode com true para ele se tornar uma array:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
return (array) $data;
break;
```

Posteriormente eu tento buscar as informações que estão na seguinte estrutura:

```
{
 "acesso":
     {
      "acessoUsuario":"usuario",
      "acessoSenha":"senha"
     }
}
```

Ao retornar os dados ja em array eu executo o $data['acesso'] e consigo a visualização a seguir:

```
{
 "acessoUsuario":"topsat",
 "acessoSenha":"4501"
}
```

Porem ao tentar os valores de dentro com $data['acesso']['acessoUsuario'] recebo o seguinte retorno:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
```

Exatamente na linha onde esta o $data['acesso']['acessoUsuario'], isto só ocorre quando tento acessar as informações mais dentro do que apenas o primeiro level da array.

Alguem conhece algum meio de eu acessar essas informações diretamente?

Comment: Você diz "e efetuo o decode com true", mas não chama `json_decode` com o `true` no segundo parâmetro. Pode conferir por favor?

Comment: Opa amigo, realmente por uma desligada acabou ficando sem o True e para mim estava tudo certo! kk Obrigado por perceber isto, agora esta funcionando!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, existe uma forme bem simples de resolver basta usar o segundo parâmetro do json_decode

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Isso acontece porque na teoria o json_decode vai pode retornar um objeto qualquer, usando o true como segundo parâmetro ele já é convertido para array.